# when iam click on download button it takes long time to goto next screen

Tags: iphone

I am new to iphone,I have a small doubt.I am working on audioPlayer project here In my screen I have a button download 
this is the screen that is [image: my initial screen having an download button in top right corner]

when we click download this code executes

- (IBAction)gotoProgressViewController:(id)sender {
  @try {

  ```
  //ShowProgressViewCont is initialized with the nibName
  showProgressViewController = [[ShowProgressViewCont alloc]initWithNibName:@"ShowProgressViewCont" bundle:nil];

  //UINavigationController is initialized with the rootViewController showProgressViewController
  navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:showProgressViewController]; 

  //The transition style of the navigationController is set to UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve
  navigationController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;

  //Presents a modal view managed by the given view controller to the user.Here navigation Controller that manages the modal view.
  [self presentModalViewController:navigationController animated:YES];
  ```

  }
  @catch(NSException * e){NSLog(@"Exception At: %s %d %s %s %@",**FILE**,**LINE**,**PRETTY_FUNCTION**,**FUNCTION**,e);}@finally{}
  }

then after click download it takes 5 to 6 sec for appear the next screen that is

[image: when we click download button in initial screen it will appears this screen]

here it consists initially having download images

my actual question is can we reduce the reaction time when we click on download button in initial screen with in 2 or 3seconds i want the second screen

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can reduce the download time, by downloading the image on a second thread, please consider this example [lazy table](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html)

it downloads the images on a second thread, increasing the responsiveness of the application